# Github: cloning using ssh works, but https doesn't work

Tags: git

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:Dev sam$ git clone https://github.com/pr.git
Cloning into 'pr'...
fatal: remote error:
  Repository not found.
admins-MacBook-Pro:Dev sam$ git clone git@github.com:pr.git
Cloning into 'pr'...
...
Checking connectivity... done.
```

As you see, `git clone` with `ssh` works, but not with `https`.
How can I make it works with `https`?

Comment: Hi @AmazingDayToday Have you get solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

1. check url

   If the url is correct, we can see the page when we enter the url.
2. check remote repo is private or public

   if the repo is a private you can't access or wrong credentials.

   Instead of

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/NAME/repo.git
   ```

   url should be

   ```
   git clone https://username:password@github.com/NAME/repo.git
   ```

Comment: I don't think username@password works. It should be username@personal_access_token